# Interpolation of Hessian matrix

Tags: splines, interpolation, hessian

I have a model where hessian matrices are calculated along a path. Since the calculation is done using finite differences, this is very time consuming.

I have tried to calculate only every second hessian matrix and interpolate in between (cubic splines). I select one entry of the Hessian matrices ($H_1[i, j], H_2[i, j], ...$) and try to interpolate this entry.

The results are okay, but it would be good to achieve a higher accuracy. Are there any promising approaches in this respect?

Comment: Try the Gauss-Siedel method as an alternative to the Hessian and finite differencing.

Comment: @nxglogic Thanks for your idea. I actually need to construct the hessians as they are needed for my calculations.